# Why is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^x(\sum_{j=1}^i\frac1j-\ln i-\gamma)}{\sum_{i=1}^x\frac1i}=\frac12$?

Tags: limits, harmonic-numbers, mathematica, euler-mascheroni-constant

$$
\mbox{Why is}\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{x}\left[\sum_{j = 1}^{i}1/j -\ln\left(i\right)-\gamma\right]}{\sum_{i = 1}^{x}1/i} =
\frac{1}{2}\ ?.$$

I learnt Euler's Constant $\gamma$ before, and I want to know the sum of $H_k-\ln k-\gamma$. [As Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=where%20%CE%B3%20is,goes%20to%20infinity), $H_k=\ln k+\gamma+\varepsilon_k$, where $\varepsilon_k\sim\frac1{2k}$. But I wonder how to prove it. By the following Mathematica program, I can check that this limit is $\frac12$. But I cannot prove it. Why is it not anything below or above $\frac12$?

```
Limit[Sum[Sum[1/j, {j, 1, i}] - Log[i] - EulerGamma, {i, 1, x}]/Sum[1/i, {i, 1, x}], x -> Infinity]
```

Comment: I remembered someone has already answered  you that you can use Stolz-Cesaro's lemma to answer your question. As far as I observe, his hint is correct, have you tried it?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen I see. That means the limit I want to calculate equals $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^x\frac1i-\ln x-\gamma}{\frac1x}$, and as wiki says, $H_k=\ln k+\gamma+\varepsilon_k$, where $\varepsilon_k\sim\frac1{2k}$, so that equals $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac x{2x}=\frac12$.

Comment: Also note that reverse Cesaro stolz doesn't always hold true.

Comment: @Alex-Github-Programmer You may find this more general result interesting as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @ParesseuxNguyen, I try to solve it with Stolz-Cesaro's lemma:

$\quad\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^x(\sum_{j=1}^i\frac1j-\ln i-\gamma)}{\sum_{i=1}^x\frac1i}\\
=\liminf\limits_{i\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^i\frac1j-\ln i-\gamma}{\frac1i}\\
=\limsup\limits_{i\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^i\frac1j-\ln i-\gamma}{\frac1i}\\
=\lim   \limits_{i\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^i\frac1j-\ln i-\gamma}{\frac1i}\\
=\lim   \limits_{i\to\infty}\frac i{2i}=\frac12$.

(Since $H_i-\ln i-\gamma\sim\frac1{2i}$, so the last equality is right.)

Comment: Why is $H_i-\log(i)-\gamma\sim\frac1{2i}$?