# Comparison between $\log _2(n)$ and $1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I did a google search and found out that $1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{10\,000}$ is approximately $12.09$

I used my calculator and found out that $\log_2(10\,000)$ is approximately $13.28$.

I want to know, is there some equation out there that relates these two. Eg $\log_2(n)$ is greater than $1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}$

Infact, what I really want is a proof that:

$\log_2(n) \ge 1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}$

I need this proof to complete my answer about Big Oh here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926601/10030693

Comment: Much more likely to get help by removing the last sentence in your post.

Comment: @AlvinL Done. I agree. I've removed it.

Comment: @AlvinL I dont know which sentence you meant though so I deleted the last two sentences

Comment: Perhaps [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) helps?

Comment: @Gilboot Lookup the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Growth_rate) and keep in mind that $\,\log_2 x \gt \ln x\,$ for $\,x \gt 1\,$

Comment: What you really need is base-$e$ ("natural") logarithms: $H_n-\ln n$ decreases from $1$ for $n=1$ with [$n\to\infty$ limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) approximating $0.577$.

Comment: @dxiv thank you very much. That's it

Comment: @Gilboot There is a complete asymptotic expansion for $H_n$ involving the natural logarithm of $n$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551025).

Answer (score 3):

Using harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k=H_n$$ Using asymptotics
$$\Delta_n=\log_2(n)-H_n=\left(\frac{1}{\log (2)}-1\right) \log (n)-\gamma -\frac{1}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ So, if your search for $n$ such that $\log_2(n)-H_n>\Delta_n$, if $n$ is sufficiently large, use
$$\left(\frac{1}{\log (2)}-1\right) \log (n)-\gamma=\Delta_n \implies n=2^{\frac{\gamma+\Delta_n }{1-\log (2)}}$$

If you want more accurate, take into account the next term and use Lambert function

$$n=\frac{\log (2)}{2 (1-\log (2))}\frac 1 {W(t)}\qquad\qquad\qquad t=\frac{\log (2)}{1-\log (2)} 2^{\frac{\gamma+\Delta_n }{\log (2)-1}-1}$$

Let $\Delta_n=1$, the first formula gives $n>35.2603$, the second one $n>36.3724$ while the exact solution is $n>36.3674$

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is incorrect. Because,

putting $n=1$, you get the false inequality $\log_21=0>1$, then putting $n=2$, you get again the false inequality $\log_22=1>1+\frac 12$.

Comment: I believe the inequality should be true for $n\geq 5$ (presumably the OP might know this and is hence why the question was tagged with `asymptotics`).

Comment: @projectilemotion Well, we need to show that  $\log_2 n>\ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \varepsilon_n$, where $n$ is large enough and $0≤\varepsilon_n ≤\frac 1{8n^2}, \gamma≈0.577$.

Comment: @User projectilemotion is right, its for an asymptotic question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926601/10030693