# Behaviour of the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}[1-(1-x)^{n-1}]\frac{dx}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, asymptotics

Consider the integral for $n\geq 2$ $$I(n)=\int_{0}^{1}[1-(1-x)^{n-1}]\frac{dx}{x} $$

> Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{I(n)}{\log n}=1$$

In integral $I(n)$, since $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx= \int_0^1 f(1-x) dx$ so we get $$I(n)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ 1-x^{n-1}  }{1-x} dx $$
So we get by using the sum of $n$ terms of a Geometric Progression $$I(n)=\int_0^1 (1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-2}) dx$$

So $$I(n)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}$$
So we obtain $$I(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$$
Now we know that
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} -\log n\right)$$
So we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(I(n)+\frac{1}{n}-\log n\right)=\gamma$$
I am struggling to prove the asymptotic. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so what is exactly your question? Ineed, you have everything needed.

Comment: @Math-fun my question is how do we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{I(n)}{\log n}=1$$ How to prove this limit?

Comment: The integral is a representation of Harmonic series, $H_n$, which behaves as $\log n + \gamma + O(1/n)$; as you have written in your answer (apart from the O term). See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks a lot. Can you please give me a reference from a book of the above formula which you wrote? Its a humble request.

Comment: I don't recall a specific book, where I could tell which page / etc :-) I am sorry. ... But you will find a lot in a "never becoming irrelevant" book by Knopp: https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Application-Infinite-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486661652

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there. You can write your last equation as
$$
0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[I(n) +\frac{1}{n} - \ln n -\gamma\right] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\ln n]\left[\frac{I(n)}{\ln n} - 1 +\frac{1}{n\ln n} - \frac{\gamma}{\ln n}\right]
$$
Since the limit of the first term in brackets is $\infty$ and the limit of the product is $0$, the limit of the second term in brackets must also be $0$. Therefore we have
$$
0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{I(n)}{\ln n} - 1 +\frac{1}{n\ln n} - \frac{\gamma}{\ln n}\right] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{I(n)}{\ln n} - 1
$$
And the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1}{n-1 \choose k}x^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1} {n-1\choose k}\frac{1}{k}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-z)^{n-1}-1}{(1-z-1)}dz$$ $$=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{z^{n-1}-1}{z-1}dz=H_{n-1}$$
Next, we have $$H_{n-1} \sim \gamma+\ln n-1/n.$$ Finally,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{I_n}{\ln n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\gamma+\ln n -1/n}{\ln n}=1.$$

Comment: Please give me a reference in a book with page number for $H_{n-1}\sim \gamma+\ln n-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Honor [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551025) is a possible derivation.

Comment: @Gary Great. Thanks a lot